# How to see what profile is default with CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Given I have the following config file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=default_access_key
aws_secret_access_key=default_secret_key

[profile testing]
aws_access_key_id=testing_access_key
aws_secret_access_key=testing_secret_key
region=us-west-2
```

And given the name of my default profile is `foo`

What CLI commands do I need to type in to get the name of my default profile. Something like:

```
$ aws describe-default-profile

{
    ...
    "default_profile_name": 'foo'
}
```

Or list all profiles and it ouputs the default too:

```
$ aws list-all-profiles

{
    [{
        ...
        profile_name: 'foo',
        "is_default": true
    }]
}
```

There is a `get-instance-profile` on `iam` ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-instance-profile.html)), but it requires the name of the profile be specified:

```
$ aws iam get-instance-profile --instance-profile-name ExampleInstanceProfile
```

Comment: Are you asking what an instance profile is?

Comment: you can always get your AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE from environment variables. Generally the default profile is tagged with name "default" unless you specify another profile in environment variables.

Answer (score 121):

You can run `aws configure list` to list your current profile

> List  the  AWS  CLI configuration data.  This command will show you the
>   current configuration data.  For each configuration item, it will  show
>   you  the  value,  where  the configuration value was retrieved, and the
>   configuration variable name.  For  example,  if  you  provide  the  AWS
>   region  in an environment variable, this command will show you the name
>   of the region you've configured, it will tell you that this value  came
>   from  an  environment  variable,  and  it will tell you the name of the
>   environment variable.
>
> To show your current configuration values:

```
      $ aws configure list
            Name                    Value             Type    Location
            ----                    -----             ----    --------
         profile                <not set>             None    None
      access_key     ****************ABCD      config_file    ~/.aws/config
      secret_key     ****************ABCD      config_file    ~/.aws/config
          region                us-west-2              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

If you want to review your configuration for a specific profile, you can run `aws configure list --profile foo`

Answer (score 38):

Since version 2 you can use:

```sh
$ aws configure list-profiles
default
test
```

To show all the available profiles.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

Answer (score 14):

The one and only

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Answer (score 4):

There are no commands in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) for viewing the profile. You would need to look at the configuration files for this information.

The `aws iam get-instance-profile` command is unrelated to the AWS CLI. It is a way of assigning a Role to an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: If you are on linux, you can:

`grep '^[[]profile' <~/.aws/config | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/]$//'`

Comment: This assumes you are using the default aws config dir location. You can also use `sed -n 's#^\[\(.*\)\]#\1#p' ~/.aws/credentials | sort -u`. On macOS change `sed` to `gsed` which you can get with `brew install gnu-sed`.

Answer (score 0):

I use these utilities in my `.bashrc` file (linux or mac)

```
# AWS
export AWS_PROFILE=default

alias awp="echo -e 'AWS_PROFILE='\$AWS_PROFILE'\n' && grep '\[profile ' ~/.aws/config | sed 's/\[profile //;s/\]//' && echo -e '\nset-awp \$1 to change'"

set-awp() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Please provide a profile name (current profile = ${AWS_PROFILE})"
    else
        export AWS_PROFILE="$1"
        echo "Switched to AWS profile: $AWS_PROFILE"
    fi
}
```

Assuming you have a standard `.aws/config` file with a default and various configs:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json

[profile personal]
...

[profile work]
...
```

This will set AWS_PROFILE to `default` on  any new terminal session, but you can change it with `set-awp`.

```
adam@laptop:~$ awp
AWS_PROFILE=default

personal
work

set-awp $1 to change
```

Then I can set it easily with

```
set-awp personal
```

And it will store that env variable for the rest of my session.